# how to create a controller based on auto configuration spring boot 1.4.0

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.4.0

I want to create a Controller in my spring boot application only in certain condition. Ex If There is bean with somename "neededBean.

This "neededBean" is in a AutoConfiguration class and it will be created only on certain condition.

I want to avoid the  Controller creation if neededBean doesnt statisfy its autoconfiguration condition.So I cannot annotate my class with @Controller as it will be created irrespective of Auto configuration class

Is there any way to achieve what I wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AbstractMvcEndpoint` is a good start for your propose.

Here is an example case, this is just give a solution for your case, but not useful for real world. 
Here I use the `@ConditionalOnClass`, but for you, need use the `@ConditionalOnBean` or `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` instead.

RabbitEndpoint.java - which only auto configured when using Tomcat.

```
/**
 * @author lhuang
 */
@ConditionalOnClass(value = Tomcat.class)
public class RabbitEndpoint extends AbstractMvcEndpoint {
    public RabbitEndpoint() {
        super("rabbit", true);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public void invoke(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(" ------ Auto-Configuration on Tomcat.class Conditional ------ ");
    }
}
```

META-INF/spring.factories, register the auto-configuration class

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=io.cloudhuang.web.RabbitEndpoint
```

Then start the spring boot app, visit the path "http://localhost:8080/rabbit"

you will get the console output

```
 ------ Auto-Configuration on Tomcat.class Conditional ------
```

Comment: Thanks Huang, This what exactly I did before I posted the question , but wanted to see if I can do without the actuator endpoint

Comment: What are you doing with the actuator endpoint? The actuator in his answer was just an example of the usage of `@ConditionalOnBean`/`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`/`@ConditionalOnClass`

Answer (score 3):

The `@Controller` is only being detected due to a component scan. You can remove the overall component scan or exclude that package by default. Then setup a `@Configuration` class that has a conditional on the other bean existing. Within that configuration you tell it to scan that controller package to add the appropriate controller.

Another option is to use the `@Profile` to only enable the controller if a specific active profile is set for the running application. You would specify that profile in the scenarios that you wanted it to be used.

Comment: Thanks Shawn will try the first approach

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at the `@ConditionalOnBean` annotation in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html).

You can add this annotation to your Controller and specify the name of your bean, so it will only be instantiated if this bean is available in your application context.

```
@ConditionalOnBean(value=MyBean.class, name="NameOfMyBean")
@Controller
public class MyController{

  ...
}
```

Comment: @ConditionalOnBean cannot be used on classes which are not Autoconfiguration, even spring documentation warns against the use of it

Comment: It CAN be used. It just should not be used, because if you do, the order of bean processing matters. That's why i linked to the docs.