# Spring boot rest controller in auto configuration library

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-autoconfiguration

I'm writing a spring boot library with autoconfiguration.

What it means is that I dont put any @Component/@Service and dont rely on class path scanning, instead I have a @AutoConfiguration class that is loaded with the AutoConfiguration.imports file.

Everything works fine, except, I want my library to include a @RestController as well.
Now, if I just annotate it with @RestController, it will be picked up by component scanning.. But if I don't annotate it, it doesnt work as a RestController. (it will be registered as a bean but the rest endpoints will throw 404 because the web mvc processor will ignore it since it's not annotated).

How can I achieve my purpose?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to design your auto-configuration to conditionally register your controller bean. Once they need it, they simply set a param in `application.properties` and a bean will be created. In this scenario, the existence of `@RestController` annotation shouldn't be a problem.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "nameOfYourLibrary.enable-controller", havingValue = "true")
public class LibraryAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Controller myController() {
        return new Controller();
    }
}
```

Update: Alternatively you can try to exclude your bean from component scanning:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = MyController.class))
public class SpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyController myController() {
        return new MyController();
    }
}
```

You also can read this article, maybe it will provide some tips where to dig further:
[how to create a controller based on auto configuration spring boot 1.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552060/how-to-create-a-controller-based-on-auto-configuration-spring-boot-1-4-0)

Comment: thanks, it doesnt work, since when you add the annotation it will already be picked up by component scanning (@Controller / @RestController basically is a meta annotation for @Component)

Comment: Hi, I already tried that before posting the question :) it doesnt work as well. It seems that the controller must be annotated with RestController/Controller to be processed by the mvc processor (I found the code that expects that annotation)

Comment: Did you try to exclude your controller class from component scanning? I've updated my answer accordingly, I did try this myself and seems like it's working as expected.

Comment: yeah i can exclude it specifically, but I wanted a generic solution. Im just wondering, if there is a normal way to do it, or maybe we are not supposed to include controllers in auto configuration at all..

Comment: Add or not to add a controller depends on your exact business requirements.
Alternatively you can look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552060/how-to-create-a-controller-based-on-auto-configuration-spring-boot-1-4-0

not sure what else I can suggest in your case, good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I also saw that post but the solution offered is specific for spring actuator. Thanks anyway for trying to help, appreciated